# Why aren't fields called "bodies" instead?

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology, fields

The discrepancy regarding the names of commutative division algebras in German and English has always startled me. In English they are called *fields*, whereas their original German name is  *Körper* (hence the $K$), a word which usually means "body" in everyday language. Nearly all other English names of algebraic objects are direct translations of the corresponding German terms (or maybe also the other way round), so I'm wondering which historic development lead to this divergence in naming conventions.

By looking up the Wikipedia article on fields in the respective languages, I found out that most languages seem to have adopted the German name. For example a field is called *corps commutatif* in French, *cuerpo* in Spanish, *Σώμα* in Greek, *corpus* in Latin, *Ciało* in Polish, *kropp* in Swedish and Norwegian.

However there also seem to be some languages where the name for fields translates to "field", such as Russian (*Поле*) and Italian (*campo*). Dutch seems to assume a special role, since the term used in the Netherlands seems to be *lichaam*, whereas the Belgians call it *veld*.

Does anyone know how this strange division in naming conventions did evolve?

Comment: I do not speak dutch, but wiktionary: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lichaam translates the everyday meaning of lichaam with body.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71129/why-is-it-called-a-ring-why-is-it-called-a-field?

Comment: Danish uses "legeme" which is also "body". In Norwegian and Danish we have both "legeme" and "kropp" as synonyms, but Norwegians chose "kropp" and the Danes chose "legeme" as the translation of Körper.

Comment: @LennartMeier: And *veld* translates to field, so the Dutch use the "German" and the Dutch-speaking Belgians the "English" term.

Comment: Curiously, in Russian, a commutative field sounds as field (поле), and a skew field sounds as body (тело). Sort of mixture.

Comment: I don't know about the history, but for me the word "field" evokes the two-dimensional nature of the complex plane, and the word "ring" the visualization of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as the complex torus $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I have wondered whether anyone else has had similar associations.

Comment: I would think the user mixedmath has given a pretty complete answer at MSE --- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71129/why-is-it-called-a-ring-why-is-it-called-a-field

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: That answer is indeed pretty interesting, but unfortunately, it doesn't provide an explanation why the German term hasn't simply been translated, as it has been the case with nearly every other mathematical term I'm aware of.

Comment: @SashaAnan'in: the same happens in Italian, where the word for skew field is "corpo" (literally, "body"). Also, in French "corps" denotes a skew field.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/a/35289/27465 and darij grinberg's comment to the OP there.

Comment: Marco: in Flemish Dutch, the same happens: they use the word *lichaam* (body) for skew field and, as noted above, *veld* (field) for field.

Comment: Same in portuguese. We use "corpo" (same word as in italian).

Comment: Wow René, really, they use *lichaam* sounds like the German *Leichnam* (corpse)...but I thought skew fields are not dead :-)

Comment: Some British mathematical papers used the term *corpus* in the early days.

Comment: A remark on local versions of french: the Belgians use "champ" (= field) for "corps commutatif", while the Swiss say as the French...

Comment: In an additional complication, the word "champ" (field) in French also refers to the algebraic structure English speakers call a "stack."  Worse and worse...

Comment: In European Spanish it is "cuerpo" indeed, but it is "campo" in Mexican Spanish, clearly by US influence. I don't know how far south in America this goes, nor whether they use "cuerpo" for skew fields. By the way, I believe that in Spain skew fields are generally called "anillos de división" (division rings) but "cuerpos no conmutativos" is not unheard of.

Comment: I personally never liked the term "field" for algebraic structures, for it leads to expressions such as "vector fields over finite fields" etc..,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be worth noting that the word "Feld" is *also* (sometimes) used in German, at least in the compound "Galoisfeld" (for "Galois field"). And, this is not some modern-day re-translation from English but classical usage (of Witt for example), see the discussion in comments of https://mathoverflow.net/a/18638/9072 for references.

In my opinion this provides additional support for anon's answer that quite at the start there were two different names and just in the one language the one 'won' whereas in the other one the other 'won' the 'competition'.

Regarding other theories and in general, it might be worth noting that "Körper" does not only mean body, like in human-body, but is also used to designate certain structures/organizations/groups, like "Justizkörper" (comprising judges, attorneys, and so on). And, in that meaning "Körper" fits a lot better with "Gruppe" (group) and also with "Ring" (also used as name for organizations, like in English) and also "Verband" (again used to designate organizations, the math meaning being lattice, in the order sense, providing another example where it is not a translation). See https://mathoverflow.net/a/117354/9072 for some discussion.
So that "Körper" is really not all that sensual in that context but quite corporate (which ultimately derives from the same source, I think).

Comment: The word 'body' has a similar alternative meaning in English (see meaning 13a in the OED).

Comment: One of the answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35286/origins-of-names-of-algebraic-structures points to some examples in the early 20th century where the terms "body" and "realm" were used in place of "field" in English.

Comment: As far as I see, the circle around Witt, F. K. Schmidt, Hasse etc. used "Körper" in the modern meaning; the only usage of "Feld" was in the compound  "Galoisfeld" for a finite field. E.g. on the last page of Witt's "Riemann-Rochscher Satz und Z-Funktion im Hyperkomplexen" he talks about an "algebraischer Funktionenkörper mit einem Galoisfeld als Konstantenkörper", that is an "algebraic function field (Körper) having a Galois field (Galoisfeld) as field (Körper) of constants".

Comment: In French too, the word "corps" can be used in this second sense. For instance, civil servants with a permanent position are organized in corps (corps des agrégés, corps des ingénieurs de l'armement, and so on).

Answer (score 14):

I think the explanation is that the concept arose somewhat independently with English-speaking mathematicians. See the discussion of the earliest known use at http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html

Comment: Interesting. Then, apparently the Chinese imported math from English speaking mathematicians (field = 域) while the Japanese did from German speakers (körper = 体).

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara Chinese 体 refers to skew field.

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara Takagi (at the turn of the century essentially the only Japanese research mathematician, as far as I know) wrote his Ph.D. thesis in German, after studying at Göttingen under the supervision of Hilbert.  German had a lot of currency as a mathematical language before the First World War.

Answer (score 6):

I once heard it was because "body" is too sensual for (Victorian?) England, so "field" was preferred. As @HJRW pointed out, this may be made up. The circumstantial evidence seems to be there, though:

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victorian_era):

> The Victorian era of British history was the period of Queen
>   Victoria's reign from 20 June 1837 until her death, on 22 January
>   1901.

[Prospect Magazine](http://www.prospectmagazine.co.uk/blog/review-holy-shit-history-swearing-melissa-mohr/#.UuECRWR6fe0):

> By the Victorian era the body had become so offensive that innocuous
>   words like “leg” were being euphemised as “limb” or “lower extremity.

Link suggested in anon's answer:

> Eliakim Hastings Moore (1862-1932) was apparently the first person to
>   use the English word field in its modern sense and the first to allow
>   for a finite field. He coined the expressions "field of order s" and
>   "Galois-field of order s = qn." These expressions appeared in print in
>   December 1893 in the Bulletin of the New York Mathematical Society
>   III. 75.

Comment: This sounds made up.  I think a source is needed.

Comment: Although there is of course some truth to the stereotype of the prudish Victorians, it's almost always overstated.

Comment: I fear the *Prospect* magazine article overstates the case.  The OED lists many polite Victorian uses of the word 'trousers' (by Charles Dickens and George Eliott, among others).  I also fear that the author has swallowed a well known *canard*.  Wikipedia says: 'there is a myth, started by Frances Trollope's *Domestic Manners of the Americans*, and later applied to the British, that furniture such as tables were covered with embroidery and tablecloths so that table legs were hidden from view, but no historical evidence suggest that this was actually practiced.'

Comment: E.H. Moore was American and, to add another curious twist, he studied in Germany!

Comment: I heard that an English translation of an early German  book in algebra used "body expansion" for a field extension. I don't know if it is true.